# Unfortunately "app" has stopped issue with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, symbols

Community

I have been having issues getting this application to operate within the AVD. When I run the application it begins to load and then the error message "Unfortunately, MyMedicare has stopped" appears. My research on Google, Stack, and Youtube alleviates nothing. Anyone got any input?

My MainActivity:

```
    package com.example.user.mymedicare;

import com.example.user.mymedicare.R;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public String result;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.MainLayout);

        Button btnCalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
        btnCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View MainLayout) {
                EditText etxtWeight = (EditText)
                        findViewById(R.id.etxtWeight);

                String strW = etxtWeight.getText().toString();
                double weight = Double.parseDouble(strW);

                EditText etxtHeight = (EditText)
                        findViewById(R.id.etxtHeight);

                String strH = etxtHeight.getText().toString();
                double height = Double.parseDouble(strH);

                double h = height * 0.01;
                double bmi = weight / (h*h);

                if (bmi <= 18.5) {
                    result = "You are Underweight!";
                }
                else if ((bmi > 18.5) && (bmi <= 25.9)) {
                    result = "You are Healthy";
                }
                else {
                    result = "You are Overweight!";
                }

                String strBmi = Double.toString(Math.round(bmi));
                TextView txtResults = (TextView)
                        findViewById(R.id.txtResults);
                txtResults.setText("Your BMI is " + strBmi + " " + result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.mymedicare"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0'
}
```

My Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.mymedicare">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
08-06 16:09:05.552 3502-3502/com.example.user.mymedicare I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
08-06 16:09:06.392 3502-3502/com.example.user.mymedicare W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.mymedicare-1/lib/x86
08-06 16:09:10.706 3502-3502/com.example.user.mymedicare W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.mymedicare-1/lib/x86
08-06 16:09:10.768 3502-3502/com.example.user.mymedicare W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-06 16:09:10.849 3502-3502/com.example.user.mymedicare D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                           --------- beginning of crash
08-06 16:09:10.849 3502-3502/com.example.user.mymedicare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.user.mymedicare, PID: 3502
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.mymedicare/com.example.user.mymedicare.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.user.mymedicare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
08-06 16:26:38.175 8171-8171/com.example.user.mymedicare W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.mymedicare-1/lib/x86
08-06 16:26:39.356 8171-8171/com.example.user.mymedicare W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.mymedicare-1/lib/x86
08-06 16:26:39.402 8171-8171/com.example.user.mymedicare W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-06 16:26:39.451 8171-8171/com.example.user.mymedicare D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-06 16:26:39.451 8171-8171/com.example.user.mymedicare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.user.mymedicare, PID: 8171
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.mymedicare/com.example.user.mymedicare.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.user.mymedicare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
08-06 16:26:42.782 8171-8171/com.example.user.mymedicare I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8171 SIG: 9
08-06 16:26:45.505 8273-8273/com.example.user.mymedicare W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.mymedicare-1/lib/x86
08-06 16:26:46.583 8273-8273/com.example.user.mymedicare W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.mymedicare-1/lib/x86
08-06 16:26:46.630 8273-8273/com.example.user.mymedicare W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-06 16:26:46.681 8273-8273/com.example.user.mymedicare D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-06 16:26:46.681 8273-8273/com.example.user.mymedicare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.user.mymedicare, PID: 8273
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.mymedicare/com.example.user.mymedicare.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.user.mymedicare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
08-06 16:26:50.049 8273-8273/com.example.user.mymedicare I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8273 SIG: 9
08-06 16:27:02.056 8388-8388/com.example.user.mymedicare W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.mymedicare-1/lib/x86
08-06 16:27:02.113 8388-8388/com.example.user.mymedicare W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-06 16:27:02.163 8388-8388/com.example.user.mymedicare D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-06 16:27:02.163 8388-8388/com.example.user.mymedicare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.user.mymedicare, PID: 8388
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.mymedicare/com.example.user.mymedicare.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.user.mymedicare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
08-06 16:27:04.722 8388-8388/com.example.user.mymedicare I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8388 SIG: 9
```

If there is anything anyone can help with, shed light on, or suggest development ideas, I am all ears and happy to hear from you.

Thanks in advance. =]

Comment: Can you provide error log?

Comment: Certainly. =]

"error: cannot find symbol variable result
error: cannot find symbol variable result
error: cannot find symbol variable result
error: cannot find symbol variable result"

Comment: check , Is there are errors in your xml files?

Comment: As I see, there are no errors in my Manifest.xml file. Are there any other files I should look at and post?

Comment: Check the layout files under res folder.

Comment: Yes this is my Activity_main.xml.
I have all my text fields properly identified, including "result". Double checking confirms this. =]

Answer (score 1):

You have commented out the `setContentView(R.layout.MainLayout);` line which effectively leaves your Activity without the xml inflated layout. So your next line `Button btnCalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);` returns `null` for your `btnCalc` object which in turn gets called on the next line which violates Java language logic and stops program execution by throwing runtime `NullPointerException`

Comment: Thank you for that, I had not noticed at first. Now the IDE is trying to tell me that the symbol "MainLayout" cannot be resolved... Which is confusing because it's definitely in my layout .xml but it has no issues with the same symbol further down the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you comment out the`setContentView(R.layout.MainLayout);`

?

Comment: Because the emulator wouldn't run with it, but the app won't run either way. Can you think of why MainLayout symbol cannot resolve? Even though I have the relative layout properly identified in the .xml?

Comment: 1)Are you sure your layout file has the name MainLayout.xml ( check case sensitivity)?  2) By the way try to type it as setContentView(com.example.user.medicare.R.mainlayout)

Comment: @Mike Kain Markov did you try my last suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to run the app again with these changes to the setContentView line, and the emulator still runs fine but the app itself won't run. The layout file is called activity_main.xml the relative layout box inside that .xml is called "MainLayout".
So, I have:
setContentView(com.example.user.mymedicare.R.layout.activity_main);
Which still won't run the MyMediCare app in the emulator.

Comment: Error:
08/07 20:03:43: Launching app
$ adb push I:\Uni\Mobile Apps\Coursework2\MyMediCare\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.user.mymedicare
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device 'emulator-5554' not found
Error while Installing APK

Comment: Maybe I have to code an installer or something? Never had to do that before hence, my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your comment , you have a `Activity_main.xml` file . But the line you have commented out is `setContentView(R.layout.MainLayout);`

Please un comment this line , and it replace `R.layout.MainLayout` with

`R.layout.Activity_main` , clean your project , do necessary import hope it will work

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't help. 

The MyMediCare app I created still will not run on the emulator.

I synced, cleaned, and altered the code, no result. =(

Comment: What error are you getting now ? Can you share your Activity_main.xml code?

Comment: Erm... the app won't run...

Also, the .xml is a layout file. No code.

Comment: It's a layout file. I've provided all code I believe to be relevant above.

Comment: Your layout file is also relevant

Comment: I think you're missing the point. 
Layout files aren't made of code, they are LAYOUT files. They contain the text boxes and buttons, titles...etc. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Sorry , I don't know what you mean . May be I need to learn more or reset my brain   to understand how  layout files aren't made of code  and xml is not  code .   Happy programming .

Answer (score -2):

Import your R class.

```
import com.example.youApp.R;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but cannot resolve symbol "youApp"

Any other ideas? =]

Comment: I'm saying add the import for YOUR class. E.G. "import com.example.user.mymedicare.R"

Comment: Your id's are stored in your R class. You cannot resolve the symbols because they class the id's are stored in (R) is not imported

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for clarifying that for me.

I have imported this properly now, it is not providing any additional errors or fixes, however. 

The symbol "result" is still unresolved.

Comment: you never declared the variable 'result' lol. Overlook your code more you're forgetting the little things.

Comment: I have done this now, and there are absolutely no errors left. Yet, it still will not compile.

Comment: Remove the onClick portion (comment it out) then try and run your app. It will help us find exactly what the issue is

Comment: You're code should be good man. Did you add the imports, and declaration of the  'result' variable before or after you un commented 'setContentView' ?

Comment: Yes, the declaration is there, it solved the symbol resolve error and let the emulator run, but the app itself won't run. Commenting out my onClick method creates lots of compiler issues around the listener of that click.

Comment: comment out the whole declaration of the listener. e.g. "btncalc.setOnClickListener(....});" only leave the part where you find the view for the butotn.